# Is beta decay accelerateable?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity, weak-interaction, half-life

Is there any way to alterate weak interaction and thus the rate of beta decay by making it slower or faster? If yes, how? Would radiating some extra bosons or neutrinos, perhaps in a focused beam, change the rate somehow?

Comment: @lurscher That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: ["A 1996 paper discusses this bound-state decay of bare-nucleus rhenium-187.  Whereas neutral rhenium-187 has a half-life of 42 × 109 years, the authors measured fully ionised rhenium-187 to have a half life of just 33 years!"](http://www.desy.de/user/projects/Physics/ParticleAndNuclear/decay_rates.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the Half-Life of Radioactive Substances](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30308/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No nuclear reaction rates can be altered as far as we know, other than by the well-known method of hitting the nuclei with neutrons.

Having said that, some people keep reporting correlations with solar activity, possibly related to some undetermined neutrino-based reactions

some not so recent articles with links to papers on the subject:

https://copaseticflow.blogspot.com/2013/05/solar-neutrinos-and-radioactive-decay.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSI_anomaly

Comment: This is not really right, since electron capture is a counterexample. Please see the question that this one duplicates (but note that the accepted answer is wrong).