# Can I excite an already unstable element for accelerated decay?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, atoms

Say I had an unstable element ready to go through beta decay and I introduced it to high speed electrons: would this lessen the time needed for the product to go through beta decay?

Comment: We see this kind of question a lot. My personal reaction is always *'I wouldn't describe that process as "decay"'*, but sure, you can forcibly dissociate nuclei.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to decrease the rate of nuclear Beta decay?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9716), [Is it possible to speed up radioactive decay rates?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52062), [Changing the Half-Life of Radioactive Substances](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30308), [Is there any thing other than time that “triggers” a radioactive atom to decay?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3228)

Comment: Why electrons in particular?

Comment: If you couldn't greatly increase the rate of decay by external radiation, we wouldn't have nuclear reactors or nuclear bombs.  What you are asking is the difference between normal half-life decay and a chain reaction.

Answer (score 1):

http://phys.org/news/2011-05-gamma-ray-laser-emit-nuclear.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_gamma_emission
Let us not forget Hf-178m2 media snit.

Nuclear decay of any kind must surmount an activation energy barrier or tunnel through it.  Pump the barrier directly or wang the nucleus overall and it proceeds at a different rate.  Electron capture additionally can be changed by reducing electron density (s,d orbitals) at the nucleus in high oxidation state fluorides [or by inclusion within a fullerene](http://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-ex/0509021).  If that atom is fully ionized, no decay at all.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, maybe not with electrons, but perhaps gamma rays....In nature there is evidence that 176Lu nuclei underwent accelerated decay in the early solar system by excitement to an unstable isomeric state. Search scholar for 176Lu-176Hf decay system in Angrite meteorites for more information

Comment: Yes, with electrons. And with photons. Both processes have been considered for radioactive waste conversion, and both work, but not with the efficiency, scale and cost that would be needed.